# Why does Environment.NewLine not work on .net label?

Tags: asp.net, label, newline, environment

I have a solution to this little problem, but I'm trying to get my head around what is happening.

I have a website with a label:

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

And on Page_load I have:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Label1.Text = "It is now: " + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
```

Why does this not produce a new line / carriage return?

I have a solution but I'm just trying to grasp what is going on and why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line break in html is [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp):

```
Label1.Text = "It is now: <br>" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: So it's just a case that the compiler renders a .net label text property as pure html.

Comment: @RicardoDeano: It's not the compiler, it's ASP.NET that renders HTML when the page gets rendered at the end of the lifecycle. But `Environment.NewLine` is not HTML at all.

Comment: @RicardoDeano: don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it answered your question. Share the love :)

Comment: Will do @ShaiCohen - still got 3mins before I can do so :D